# Row draw corrupt renderWith function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I am rendering the column with below render function:

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Validation').renderWith(validationRenderer)

function validationRenderer(data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<div class="btn-group">' +
      '<label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">' +
      '<input ng-click="vm.toggleValidation($event, ' + data.id + ', '+meta.row+', '+meta.col+')" name="validation'+data.id+'" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="YES"> Yes' +
      '</label>' +
      '<label class="btn btn-default btn-sm">' +
      '<input ng-click="vm.toggleValidation($event, ' + data.id + ', '+meta.row+', '+meta.col+')" name="validation'+data.id+'" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="NO"> No' +
      '</label>' +
      '</div>';
}
```

When user clicks on a radio button, below `vm.toggleValidation` function is triggered:

```
vm.toggleValidation = toggleValidation;
function toggleValidation(event, id, rowNum, colNum) {
  event.stopPropagation();

  // call to a server and then redraw ...

  $log.info('Updating row and re-drawing it..');
  var table = vm.dtInstance.DataTable;
  var row = table.row(rowNum);
  var rowData = row.data();
  rowData.validation = event.target.value;
  table.row(rowNum).data(rowData).draw(false);
}
```

Rendered radio buttons stopped working as soon as redraw is complete. I can see radio buttons but `toggleValidation` is not getting called upon clicking on a radio button. Radio button works only once. If I remove `draw` function it works perfectly so there is something wrong in redrawing the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate your scenario, but: The reason is that you in fact modify the DOM by `draw()` and by that the angular directives is resetted. You need to reinitialise the directives by using `$compile`. I guess the following would work :

```js
table.row(rowNum).data(rowData).draw(false);
$compile( table.row(rowNum).nodes() )($scope);
```

If it is not working,, add a

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.$digest()
})
```

as well. But do not think it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

you're appending  a template that refer to the current scope (see call to `vm.toggleValidation`), this needs an explicit call to the $compile method, otherwise the element won't be bound to the scope and will be rendered as a static content.

```
DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Validation')
.renderWith($compile(validationRenderer)($scope))
```